# How to change the amount of fields that can be posted in a form with IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis, iis-7, coldfusion, iis-7.5, http-post

We've hit a problem with some forms in the admin portion of our web app.  There are a handful of forms that contain a large number of fields (it can range anywhere from one input field to the hundreds).

We've found that as these forms grow, there is a point where the server will throw 500 errors when a form is posted.

After running a test, I was able to find that the server can handle forms with 100 fields in them; once 101 or more fields are used, we get the errors.

We run Coldfusion, and we have determined that Coldfusion is not throwing this error.  We never see this error logged in Coldfusion, so we are assuming IIS is throwing an error even before it sends the request to the Coldfusion server.

I'm assuming there is some setting in IIS 7.5 where we can up this limit.  I've searched on the web, but all I can find is how to raise the byte-size limits of this data, not any kind of limit on a number of fields that are allowed.

So, am I right in assuming that this can be changed, and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an issue introduced with hotfix APSB12-06. While it is a ColdFusion error, people have reported [receiving the error in Tomcat, before it supposedly hit the CF server](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4540754)

There is a setting in `neo-runtime.xml` which defines the `postsizelimit` - and is defaulted to 100.

The full notes are located [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-security-hotfix-apsb12-15.html), but here is the short version.

*This hot fix has a new setting in ColdFusion, Post Parameter Limit. This setting limits the number of parameters in a post request. The default value is 100. If a post request contains more parameters as specified, the server doesn't process the request and throws an exception. This process protects against DoS attack using Hash Collision. This setting is different from Post Size Limit (ColdFusion Administrator > Settings > Maximum size of post data). This setting isn't exposed in the ColdFusion Administrator console. But you can easily change this limit in the neo-runtime.xml file. See point 5 below.
Customers who want to change postParameterLimit, go to {ColdFusion-Home}/lib for Server Installation or {ColdFusion-Home}/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib for Multiserver or J2EE installation. Open file neo-runtime.xml, after line.*

```
<var name='postSizeLimit'><number>100.0</number></var>
```

*Add the line below and you can change 100 with the desired number.*

```
<var name='postParametersLimit'><number>100.0</number></var>
```

CF10+ has the setting available to edit within the CF Admin Settings page under `Maximum number of POST request parameters` under `Server Settings -> Settings`.

On our 9.0.1 server, we just increased the setting up to 10000 and have seen no adverse effects.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I assume this will require a restart of the CF server to actually be used? Also, if this is was Coldfusion throwing the error, would you know and reason why this wouldn't be logged in the CF Server Monitor in the errors section?

Comment: I believe so. I know we did just to be sure. I'm not really sure why the issue appears as a web server issue versus CF server, but servers make my head spin.

Comment: @phantom42 The request is probably being rejected at the connector level rather than at the application server level. This means that the application server never has to process any part of the request, but obviously this does make it look like a web server problem. (iis certainly has its fair share)

Comment: @phantom42 This seems to have raised the limit, and has solved our problem, but it isn't working exactly right. I raised the limit to 1000, but I used my test script and I was able to submit more than 1000 fields (I tried 10000 fields and while it took longer, it did take it)...

Comment: You're saying that the limit wasn't being properly enforced after you raised it?

Comment: @phantom42 Yes, the limit is not being enforced. I have a script to test this all with; it uses a URL param to insert a bunch of blank inputs into a form that it then tries to submit to itself. Before making this change, it started throwing errors when the form got 101 or more fields. I have the variable in the XML file set to "1000.0" (I double checked it), but I can submit 1001 fields and I was able to event submit 10,000 fields. So it's raising the cap, but not to what I set it to...

Comment: This is the first I've heard of that. You may want to open a separate question to see if anyone knows more about it.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are bumping up against a security feature of ColdFusion.  What ColdFusion version are you running?  In [ColdFusion Security Hotfix APSB12-06](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-security-hotfix.html) they introduced a fix to protect against DoS attack using Hash Collision.  From that page:

> This hotfix implements a new setting in ColdFusion, Post Parameter
>   Limit. This limits the number of parameters in a post request. The
>   default value is 100. If a post request contains more parameters as
>   specified, server will not process the request and throws an
>   exception. This is done to protect against DoS attack using Hash
>   Collision. This setting is different from Post Size Limit (ColdFusion
>   Administrator > Settings > Maximum size of post data). We are not
>   exposing this setting in ColdFusion Administrator console, but this
>   limit can be easily changed in neo-runtime.xml file. See point 5
>   below.

Also on that page are instructions on how to increase that limit. Basically you have to make a change in your neo-runtime.xml file.

> Customers who want to change postParameterLimit, go to
>   `{ColdFusion-Home}/lib` for Server Installation or
>   `{ColdFusion-Home}/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib` for Multiserver or J2EE
>   installation. Open file neo-runtime.xml, after line:
>
> ```
> <var name='postSizeLimit'><number>100.0</number></var>
> ```
>
> add the below line and you can change 100 with desired number.
>
> ```
> <var name='postParametersLimit'><number>100.0</number></var>
> ```