# Best way to AJAX submit a form with unknown number of elements

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

This is more of a logical/best-practice question than pure programming so apologies if its against the rules.

I am submitting some of my forms using JQuery's AJAX features as such:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: form-actions.cfc?method=NewSubmission,   
      data: $('#form1').serialize(),
      success: function (result) {
         // alert user of success
      }
      error: function (result) {
         // alert user of success
      }
 });
```

The form is being submitted to a ColdFusion Component which takes all the parameters of the form that have been serialized and puts them into variables before inserting into a SQL database. Here is an example:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="NewSubmission" access="remote" hint="Saves or Submits New Submission" returntype="JSON">
  <cfargument name="CustomerID" type="numeric" />
  <cfargument name="Name" type="any" />
  <cfargument name="DOB" type="any" />
     <cfquery>
      ...the cfarguments automatically map to the key:value pairs 
      submitted by JQuery and insert into SQL here...
     </cfquery>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

MAIN QUESTION: I now have a form which can have anything from 0-infinity `<input type="file" name="upload1" />` elements because they are dynamically generated by the user clicking on a button that says "add file". Each time this button is clicked, a new `<li>` is generated with a new input field.

Because I don't know how many files the person wants to upload, I can't seem to setup the CFC to handle them. I was thinking of this option to handle this situation:

1. Create a variable in JQuery like this: `var numoffiles = $('#FileUploader ul li').size();` which counts how many `<li>` elements I have in my FileUploader div. However many this is must be the amount of files the user wants to upload. I have to then pass this number in my form submission to the CFC so that it will dynamically create the appropriate number of CFARGUMENTS to handle the filenames being uploaded. It must create these CFARGUMENTS before being able to map the key:value pairs. I'm not sure if it can do this.

Could anyone please suggest another way or a better way to do this? I'm thinking that I'm missing a trick somewhere because my solution seems a bit primitive.

Comment: in coldfusion, there's a form field called `fieldnames`, accessed with `form.fieldnames`. Given this you could iterate over the list contained within it, handling the ones that match the names of your file fields. Then, instead of passing each form field as a separate argument, pass an array of file fields and iterate over the array.

Comment: `$('#form1').serialize() + '&numb=' + $('#form1 input[type="file"]').length`

Comment: Is your form submitting directly to the cfc, or is it submitting to an act page that is interacting with the cfc

Comment: Submitting directly to the CFC in the <form action="cfc"> part.

Comment: I'm not currently using JQuery to submit my forms. They go direct to the CFC. But the issue of unknown number of fileupload elements made me think I had to go the ajax route. Especially as the form may hang for ages when submitting directly to CFC without any feedback to the user. At least Jquery can provide a spinner or something.

Comment: In that case you can access all of the arguments through the arguments structure. `<cfdump var="#arguments#">` you don't have to specify an argument using the cfargument tag to receive it.

Comment: As far as the form hanging for ages, it will hang regardless for the duration of the upload (unless you want to risk the user leaving the page, interrupting the upload), however you could then off-load the processing of the uploaded files to a separate process that the user doesn't have to wait on.

Comment: Can you explain what I can do with the #arguments# structure in this situation? Am I right in thinking that everything that is being submitted to the CFC will automatically be stored in the #arguments# structure? Is there an easy way to submit the form to the CFC and have it dump the #arguments# structure back to the page so I can work out how to deal with it?

Comment: Yes, add the cfdump like in my comment, then navigate to the cfc manually in your browser. `http://foo.com/test.cfc?method=mymethod&somearg=somevalue` Your defined arguments will either have their default value, or null if no default was supplied, and then it will list any additional arguments that were passed with their values.

Comment: Wonderful... so the next logical step would be setup a loop in the CFC to insert the value of each 'upload' argument value into the database. Now I'm stuck again :( how do I get CF to loop over each argument where its name is like 'upload'?

Comment: it's a structure, so all you need to do is loop over the keys in the structure looking for keys that have a matching name. Here's a sample, an old sample, but still valid: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=arrayStruct_11.html In that sample, you would just ensure that `person` starts with `upload` using the `find` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry about creating a counter, do this...

```
<!---this cfset is for demo purposes, you will leave this line out--->    
<cfset form.fieldnames="someOtherFieldsYouMayHave,upload1,upload2,upload3,upload4,upload5">
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="i">
  <cfif left(i,6) eq "upload">
    <cfoutput>processing #i#...<br/></cfoutput>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
output:
processing upload1...
processing upload2...
processing upload3...
processing upload4...
processing upload5...
```

NOTE: Since you say it could be infinity you should take note of the new setting in Cf10: "Maximum number of POST request parameters".  You may have to up this number from it's default which I believe is 100.  If you are below ColdFusion 10 you can edit this setting in one of the xml files.  You can read about it here: http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-security-hotfix.html

Comment: For ColdFusion 10, the "Maximum number of POST request parameters" can be adjusted in the xml files or the CF Administrator.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882788/how-to-change-the-amount-of-fields-that-can-be-posted-in-a-form-with-iis-7-5